# передача полученного значения с ajax в timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

у меня есть timepicker на jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
         timeFormat: 'H:i',
         minTime: '8', 
         maxTime: '19',
         step: 60,
         disableTimeRanges: [
            ['11:00', '11:01'],
            ['16:00', '16:01']
        ]
    });
});
```

и есть ajax запрос к серверу где я получаю время с бд на сервере.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'time_from_ajax/',
    type: 'get', // can be 'post' as well or anything else you'd want such as 'put', 'patch', etc'
    data: {'datetime': datetime},
    success: function(e){
         console.log(e)
         var time=e 
    },
    error: function(e){
         console.log(e);
    }
})
```

как это все объединить чтобы в `disableTimeRanges` записывалась переменная `var time` и чтобы она постоянно обновлялась при смене даты, т.к. на разных датах разное время.
вроде в доках что-то сказано про onChange , но не могу разобраться как это прикрутить
https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery
подскажите как сделать ? если это вообще возможно 
или какие есть альтернативы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал так. все обновляется при смене дат

```
$.ajax({
url: 'time_from_ajax/',
type: 'get', 
data: {'datetime': datetime, 'val':val},
success: function(e){
     console.log(e)
     var leng = e['time_list'].length;
     let disRange = [ ]
     $(function() {
     $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
         timeFormat: 'H:i',
         minTime: '8', 
         maxTime: '19',
         step: 60,
         disableTimeRanges: [],
         listWidth:1,
         disableTextInput: true,
    });
    $('#id_time_visit').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disRange);   
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
         timeFormat: 'H:i',
         minTime: '8', 
         maxTime: '19',
         step: 60,
         disableTimeRanges: []
    });
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'time_from_ajax/',
    type: 'get', // can be 'post' as well or anything else you'd want such as 'put', 'patch', etc'
    data: {'datetime': datetime},
    success: function(e){
         console.log(e)
         var time=e;
         $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
             timeFormat: 'H:i',
             minTime: '8', 
             maxTime: '19',
             step: 60,
             disableTimeRanges: time
         });
    },
    error: function(e){
         console.log(e);
    }
})
```

Comment: недоступное время не обновляется после того как 1 раз выбралось